# proxy settings don't help with update manager

Tags: update-manager, proxy

I'm currently behind a proxy at my university. I can access the www on this computer by changing chromium's proxy settings.

I can also use the command line apt-get only by running this function each time:

```
function uniproxy()
{
  read -s -p ">> " mypassword
  export http_proxy=http://myusername:$mypassword@wwwproxy.stuff.is.here:8000
  export https_proxy=http://myusername:$mypassword@wwwproxy.stuff.is.here:8000
  export ftp_proxy=http://myusername:$mypassword@wwwproxy.stuff.is.here:8000
  echo ""
}
```

When I change preferences>networks proxy appropriately, it won't let me use command-line apt-get. More importantly though, update manager cannot connect even when I change the aforementioned settings. I also changed the synaptic settings to see if that would help, but alas - update manager won't connect.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a bug in 11.04 to do with this as I was able to use the apt.conf and the 'Apply System Wide' button in the GUI proxy settings panel previously but now nothing works (except the command line solution you've given in the question)

Comment: Weird: I rebooted and the changes to the proxy settings for Update Manager started working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try creating a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with the following contents:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://myusername:$mypassword@wwwproxy.stuff.is.here:8000";
```

That should work for any apt invocation, whether it is through the command line, synaptic or update-manager.

Comment: I just gave this a shot, but no dice :(.

Comment: It changes it so I don't have to use the uniproxy function when i use command line apt-get, but the GUI stuff still won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It just solved the GUI problem also and I upgraded to ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 11.04.  It looks like this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: James, where would we find documentation to explain why/how this works?

Comment: For those who don't pay attention: `$mypassword` is a variable, so if one would not use a variable they should not use the `$` sign. @James Henstridge, I suggest that you emphasize that it's a variable name, or careless people like me who look directly at the answer my miss this point (as trivial as it may be).

Answer (score 1):

After editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf` as [per James' suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32947/proxy-settings-dont-help-with-update-manager/32969#32969), run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal.

This worked for me. Admittedly I have no idea why.

Also, I found `apt-config dump` to be useful at catching syntax errors in the apt.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I resolved it by clicking the "Apply system-wide" button on the proxy settings in System Settings. The apply button isn't that noticeable.