# Ubuntu in Oracle Virtual Box running on Windows 7

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-7

I am trying to get Ubuntu version 14.04.1 running on a Windows 7 64 bit system. The Oracle VirtualBox is version 5.0.12r104815.

From a terminal window in Ubuntu I am able to ping google.com and other addresses. But I cannot get the system to update or install other software.

I have the default horrible 640x480 resolution which I cannot change and want to install the tools to change the resolution.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I get an instant response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-dkms
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-x11
```

When I try to run an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The response is a continuous:

```
0% [Connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.201...
```

I can't open google.com in firefox either, yet I can ping google.com

I have setup the system with the correct company DNS address. All the host names and addresses will ping ok, but I can't get any data response back to the system.  I suspect it is a firewall problem.  The companies IT dept has experience in Windows only, what ports do I need to ensure are opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I believe the problem was related to our firewall, I set-up a proxy and everything now works, the information came from this post:

[proxy settings don't help with update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32947/proxy-settings-dont-help-with-update-manager)

Answer (score 0):

first check if gateway is setup correctly

```
#route
```

check the gateway if not ok then

```
#route delete default gw (your gateway ip)

#route add default gw (your gateway ip)
```

then

do a

## DNS

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

## apt-get

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to read the results to see if it is working correctly or not.

Comment: ok , you can ping out of the network so the gateway is working ok, can you resolve names ? if not then have to fix dns , if your using nat which i don't recomend it should , nat should work out of the box. I recomend using the ubuntu vm as briged adapter and give apropriate ip with dhcp or manually  ,then add 208.67.222.222(opendns server) in /etc/resolv.conf or add it in /etc/network/interfaces, then if still cant get-http forwaord the ports as i said with iptables command ,then let me know

Comment: I can ping the IP's and I can ping the name's which then resolve to an IP address, but I cannot use either in a browser.  I did notice that the Gateway IP address isn't correct, however when I tried to change it with "route add"  I got "Network is unreachable".

Comment: of course cause its using nat, i know you have your reaons to use nat but i would suggest using the ubuntu vm as a briged adapter ,that way it will be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: With the adapter set to "Bridged Adapter" the network icon in the top line just spins continuously then I get a message informing me that the Network is disconnected.

Comment: #service network-manager stop

#ifconfig eth0 up

#dhclient -r eth0 && dhclient eth0

Comment: use these commands this stops network manager and gives eth0 a ip address from dhcp if you dont have a dhcp server setup in your local network then do it manually

Comment: #ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.53/24 (your ip which does not conflicts with other hosts on your local network)
#route add default gw 192.168.0.1(your local gateway)
#echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" > /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: also read this link about your nat problem just fr info http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1786307.html

Comment: Settings, IPv4, IP Address 10.1.1.138, Broadcast address: 10.1.255.255, Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0, Default Route: 10.1.0.242, Primary DNS: 10.1.0.241, Secondary DNS: 8.8.8.8, Ternary DNS: 8.8.4.4

Comment: last tip from me disable ufw completely 

#sudo ufw disable

hope you get it working ,maybe someone more experienced shall answer ,sorry i wasn't any help